# Why is Google's Yolo tool giving me an unsupportedBrowser error?

Tags: javascript, google-signin, google-identity

I'm using Google's [You Only Login Once](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/) tool (`googleyolo`) on my webpage.  It worked fine when testing on localhost, but as soon as I pushed to the server, I started getting an `unsupportedBrowser` error.  This error isn't mentioned on their [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/troubleshooting) page, nor is it in the [list of possible errors](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/retrieve-hints#handle_the_hint_request_result).  I'm using the same browser (Chrome v63.0.3239.84) to hit both pages.  According to the troubleshooting page, Chrome is a supported browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an absolutely terrible error message - the problem lies nowhere near your browser or the support for it.  Rather, the issue lies in the fact that Google's one-tap signup/signin tooling requires a page loaded over a secure connection (i.e. `https`).  `localhost` is considered 'secure' for ease of debugging, which is why it worked there but not when you loaded the page from an actual server.

Comment: Hi @SomeKittens, we added an warning in the console when running over http. Let me know if that works!